# Adding menu items during runtime in C#

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, click

I'm still working on getting a menu to display all of the input devices on a computer- pardon my third question in something that is probably very simple.

Here's the code:

```
List<MenuItem> inputDevice = new List<MenuItem>();
MenuItem myMenuItemInputDevices = new MenuItem("&Input Devices");
sgFileMenu.MenuItems.Add(myMenuItemInputDevice);
for (int i = 0; i < DeviceCount; i++)
{
    inputDeviceMenu.Add(new MenuItem(inputName[i]));
    myMenuItemInputDevices.MenuItems.Add(inputDeviceMenu[i]);
    myMenuItemInputDevices.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.myMenuItemInputDeviceClick);
}
```

This seems to work just fine, the menu items are added, everything is good, but clicks on the dropdown list are not working.  I've done other work with menus, and clicks in other code are working correctly.  I tried putting

```
myMenuItemInputDevices.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.myMenuItemInputDeviceClick);
```

outside of the {}, just in case that was the right way to do it, but that didn't help.

What am I missing?

Comment: I assume inputName[i] is the dropdown items that are not working?

Comment: inputName[i] is the dropdown items, but that part is working fine.

Comment: What's the difference between inputDeviceMenu and myMenuItemInputDevices? I can see only what is the second one.

Answer (score 2):

You want this

```
List<MenuItem> inputDevice = new List<MenuItem>();
MenuItem myMenuItemInputDevices = new MenuItem("&Input Devices");
sgFileMenu.MenuItems.Add(myMenuItemInputDevice);
for (int i = 0; i < DeviceCount; i++)
{
    inputDeviceMenu.Add(new MenuItem(inputName[i]));
    inputDeviceMenu[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(this.myMenuItemInputDeviceClick);
    myMenuItemInputDevices.MenuItems.Add(inputDeviceMenu[i]);
    myMenuItemInputDevices.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.myMenuItemInputDeviceClick);
}
```

EDIT: It is pretty obvious that the Menu Items that you are trying to add does not have any Click event method hooked up.

```
    inputDeviceMenu.Add(new MenuItem(inputName[i]));
```

You are just adding them.

Comment: You have the right answer but the code is probably wrong. The `inputName[i]` is not a MenuItem but I suppose a string

Comment: Very close- this is what works: inputDeviceMenu[i].Click += new System.EventHandler(this.myMenuItemInputDeviceClick);